# Android - "set-device-owner" with non rooted device

Tags: android, kiosk, kiosk-mode

We have to create a kiosk mode android app.
The app is ready, we need only to set kiosk mode.

We want to set the "set-device-owner" programmatically but our tablet is not rooted.
We don't want use ADB because this can be hard to explain to our customer.

Is there another way to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use QR code provisioning to get device owner privilege.

After factory reset on the welcome screen, tap Welcome 6 times to enter QR code provisioning mode. Here you can scan your QR code that is generated using the following code to activate device owner.

{"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME": "in.test.mdm/in.test.mdm.AdminReceiver", "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_CHECKSUM": "AVMYPJsNa1nCkf0jdWPEY7x_wnfYaIh1ouWuq10rYZY", "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION": "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1XqplR-QKO_iUqdm6RAjAPeAAGwoI6uFj&export=download", "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_LEAVE_ALL_SYSTEM_APPS_ENABLED":true,"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_SKIP_ENCRYPTION":true,"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_ADMIN_EXTRAS_BUNDLE":{"test":"test" } }

You can generate a qr code by pasting the above text in any qr code generator site  for example : https://www.the-qrcode-generator.com/